# SMS Resend + Async Task

Tags: android, sms

i am developing APP which send sms to Number, if SMS failed the Asynctask execute and check after interval to resend sms again but, all my work wasted because i don't understand the Asynctask **here is my Code.**

**ASYNC Class**

```
        class checkList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        public Void doInBackground(String... p) {
          while (true) {
                already_running_async=true;
              sms.sendTextMessage(phone_nr, null, "SmS Sending", sentPI, null);

              try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              if (isCancelled()) break;

          }
        return null;
        }
        };
```

**SMS sending Code and Error Handling**

```
        bol=false;
    already_running_async=false;
    check=false;

sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        if(!phone_nr.equals(""))
            sms.sendTextMessage(phone_nr, null,"Sms body" , sentPI, null); 
        sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
         @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                   case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                       //sms sent if bol true cancel the Asynctask :)
                    if(bol){
                    new checkList().cancel(true);}
                    break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        if(already_running_async==false){
                        new checkList().execute();
                        bol=true;}
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        if(already_running_async==false){
                        new checkList().execute();
                        bol=true;}
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        if(already_running_async==false){
                        new checkList().execute();
                        bol=true;}
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        if(already_running_async==false){
                        new checkList().execute();
                        bol=true;}
                        break;
                }

           }
        };
        registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

**Problem:**
 task starts but task remain alive and send sms repeatedly after 10 second i have also put the cancel but asyntask doesnot cancel after successfull sms is sent

Please Help i havent Slept for Night because of this problem :(

Regards

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is. Does the text not send? Does the task not start? Is something throwing an error?

Comment: hello , task starts but task remain alive and send sms repeatedly after 10 second i have also put the cancel but asyntask doesnot cancel after successfull sms is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case creates a *new* asynctask that is immediately canceled.

```
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
    //sms sent if bol true cancel the Asynctask :)
    if(bol){
        new checkList().cancel(true);
    }
    break;
```

To cancel the AsyncTask you need to store it in a variable, like

```
checkList smsTask = new checkList();
smsTask.execute();

// Other app logic

// Replacing the internal portion of that case is the new cancel code
if (bol) {
    smsTask.cancel(true);
}
```

Comment: mean only logic is to create an object of Async Task? rest code is perfect for resending/ retry of failure sms ? can u please also check and simulate my code orally thanx

Comment: The problem isn't when the task is created, but in not storing a reference to it. Also, you might want to consider shifting the logic for checking if sending succeeded or failed into the AsyncTask itself. Then the task can determine if it needs to continue attempting to send, and you'll only need to cancel from outside if you're wanting to halt attempts. In addition, your main thread won't be blocked at all by checking on SMS status. I'm not sure if the rest of the code is perfect without actually building and compiling everything, but it *looks* ok.

Comment: i have created object of AsyncTask but its saying build final object for async task is this normal and in this way Asynctask smstask not starting at all by smstask.execute();

Comment: can u please tell how can i build login inside of aynctask for checking sms send or failed thanx